# Масштабирование графа на плоскости (геометрия)

Tags: графы, алгоритм, c++, масштабирование

Есть набор вершин, отображённых симметрично началу координат (условной точке).
Отображается скученно, т.к. координаты вершин - самые разные от 0.000 .. 1000.000 по обоим осям.
Как вывести граф, чтобы он заполнил собой всю прямоугольную канву (отмасштабировать, убрать скученность вершин)?

Уточняю. Работаю в RAD Studio XE5, C++ Builder. Граф вывожу на канву компонента `Image (1000x700 px)`.
На данный момент граф отцентрирован в Image и выводится в координаты `currentX`, `currentY`:

```
double deltaX = ((Image1Width) /2  - (maxX-minX)/2);
double deltaY = ((Image1Height)/2 -  (maxY-minY)/2);
double currentX = deltaX + StrToFloat(OBOD_XCoord->Strings[i]);
double currentY = deltaY + StrToFloat(OBOD_YCoord->Strings[i]);
```

где `maxX`, `minX`, `maxY`, `minY` - максимумы и минимумы координат вершин по обоим осям, а `OBOD_XCoord`, `OBOD_YCoord` - исходные координаты вершин.

Как отмасштабировать граф (как можно крупнее), дабы избежать скученности вершин?

Comment: Почему бы не подсчитать минимальную и максимальную координаты вершин, и при выводе линейно отобразить на координаты целевого прямоугольника на экране?

Comment: VladD, это уже частично сделано. Но коэффициент масштабирования пока не подобран, т.к. есть завязка на исходные координаты вершин в файле